# Xcode 9.2 Building failed without showing any errors

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, compilation

**Update**

I know the problem isn't within the pods the problem only happens when I start refactoring the project changing existing classes or so then when I try to build the project it simply fails with no error unless I'm in the file itself which has the error.

**Problem**

I'm trying to refactoring existing project on a separated branch but as it showed in the attached link the Xcode not showing any errors but it keeps failing

**Note:**

what I've tried to:

- Clean and Build
- Clean and Quit -> Xcode
- Change build setting to show all compiled items

**Video showing the issue**
[Preview for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svwOo.jpg)

Comment: do you use by chance any pod ?

Comment: yup but changes I've done I think not affected any pod

Comment: try to update your pods and rebuild from workspace

Comment: the pods aren't related please check the update which I just added

Comment: Did you check a build log?

Comment: Thanks @Axazeano it works

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pods for your project, then quit xcode update your pods with `pod update` a